# How to transmit ArrayList to other activity in android?

Tags: java, android, arraylist

In android I have an `ArrayList`as follows:

```
ArrayList<SinglePoint> pointlist = new ArrayList<SinglePoint>();
```

which I will with content. When I am finished with the current activity, I need to transmit this object `pointlist` to a new activity. I tried the following (as I have found in several SO answers):

```
intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("pointlist", pointlist);
```

and in the new activity I have the line

```
ArrayList<SinglePoint> pointlist = (ArrayList<SinglePoint>)getIntent().getSerializableExtra("pointlist");
```

but for the second line I get the error

```
Error:(40, 56) error: incompatible types: ArrayList<SinglePoint> cannot be converted to ArrayList<? extends Parcelable>
```

How to fix that?

I also tried the suggestion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21250339/how-to-pass-arraylistcustomeobject-from-one-activity-to-another) which also does not work.

And with the following code as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15790499/passing-arraylist-of-objects-between-activities)

```
intent.putExtra("pointlist", pointlist);
```

and

```
ArrayList<SinglePoint> pointlist = (ArrayList<SinglePoint>)getIntent().getSerializableExtra("pointlist");
```

I get the error

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcel: unable to marshal value com.impyiablue.checkpoint.tools.SinglePoint@2f4a7cec
```

Comment: Does SinglePoint implement Parcelable?

Comment: No. What is Parcelable?

Comment: You need SinglePoint implement Parcelable to pass list to other activity. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html

Comment: And then I must define some extra functions? Why is this so complicated...?

Comment: As @Raghunandan says, you need to implement `Parcalable` in your SinglePoint if you want to use `putParcelableArrayListExtra`. Or implement `Serializable` if you want to use `PutSerializable`.

Comment: also if your list in huge i would recommend storing it persistently and then retrieve it in another activity. There is a limit as to how much data you can transfer. Not sure of the exact limit value

Comment: `.getSerializableExtra("pointlist")` <-- `getParcelableArrayListExtra("pointlist")`, surely? (In addition to the fact that `SinglePoint` will need to implement `Parcelable`...)

Comment: How do I flatten my object with two objects in it? A String and a Long?

Comment: You need extra code if you want to implement Parcelable. You only need to add implement Serializable to your SinglePoint if you want to use Serializable. Like this: `SinglePoint implements Serializable{ }`

Comment: With serialisable it did work! Thanks

Comment: @Alex use parcelable instead of searlization https://www.3pillarglobal.com/insights/parcelable-vs-java-serialization-in-android-app-development

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46752761/3395198 Use Parcelable

Comment: Congrats! Btw, most people tell that Parcelable is more faster than Serializable. But please look at this test project: https://bitbucket.org/afrishman/androidserializationtest. For persisting the data, use Serializable. Never use Parcelable for it!

Answer (score 0):

You only need to implement the Parcelable interface for SinglePoint

This could help
[AndroidParcelable](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidParcelable/article.html)